# Modify/flatten result from sql one to many query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

Consider the following simplified schema example -

```
sys_systems

id   name
---------------------
1    Inventory


sys_shadow_data

id   primary_key_value   sys_schema_id   field_value
---------------------------------------------------------
1    1                   143             Awaiting audit
2    1                   144             90


sys_schemas

id      field_name
-------------------
143     notes
144     status
```

The following query -

```
select sys_systems.*, 
(select sys_shadow_data.field_value where sys_schemas.field_name = 'status') as status, 
(select sys_shadow_data.field_value where sys_schemas.field_name = 'notes') as notes 
from sys_systems
    left join sys_shadow_data
        on sys_systems.id = sys_shadow_data.primary_key_value
            left join sys_schemas
                on sys_schemas.id = sys_shadow_data.sys_schema_id
```

yields -

```
id   name       status    notes
-----------------------------------------
1    Inventory  90        null
1    Inventory  null      Awaiting audit
```

The result I would like to obtain is -

```
id   name       status    notes
-----------------------------------------
1    Inventory  90        Awaiting audit
```

Is there a change I can make to the sql query to achieve this or is this a case whereby I would need to process the results in the application code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query amounts to pivoting the joined tables on the `field_name` column from the `sys_schemas` table to generate new columns for each value in that column.  You can `GROUP BY` the inventory ID and name, then use `MAX` to collapse the two records into one:

```
SELECT sys_systems.id,
       sys_systems.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sys_schemas.field_name = 'status'
                THEN sys_shadow_data.field_value ELSE NULL END) AS status, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN sys_schemas.field_name = 'notes'
                THEN sys_shadow_data.field_value ELSE NULL END) AS notes 
FROM sys_systems
LEFT JOIN sys_shadow_data
    ON sys_systems.id = sys_shadow_data.primary_key_value
LEFT JOIN sys_schemas
    ON sys_schemas.id = sys_shadow_data.sys_schema_id
GROUP BY sys_systems.id,
         sys_systems.name
```

Comment: That sql give's me an error -

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select sys_shadow_data.field_value where sys_schemas.field_name = 'status' at line 3

Any idea why?

Comment: There was a typo in the query.  `FROM` was mispelled as `FEOM`.  Sorry.

Comment: I had already spotted that Tim. The error occurs even after correcting FEOM to FROM ;-). SQL isn't my strong point so I'm not sure how to fix the error. Hopefully you can still help.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much for your help Tim, works perfectly.